# How to change the keyboard shortcut for Firefox's context menu?

Tags: firefox, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, context-menu, xul

I am trying to change the keyboard shortcut for showing the context menu in Firefox (the equivalent of pressing `Shift-F10` on Linux or Windows or `Control-Space` on OS X).  It seems like this shortcut is handled at a different level from normal keyboard shortcuts (it doesn't show up in the [Keyconfig extension](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994) that allows remapping of most keyboard shortcuts).

I have tried creating key and mouse events to trigger the context menu (using the following code that is mapped to a shortcut with Keyconfig) but they haven't worked so far.  I haven't been able to track down where in the source code Firefox handles the keyboard shortcut for the context menu or if there is a single function that I could call to show it.

Mouse event:

```
var focused = document.commandDispatcher.focusedElement;
if(!focused) focused = document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow.document.activeElement;
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 2, null);
focused.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Key event:

```
var focused = document.commandDispatcher.focusedElement;
if(!focused) focused = document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow.document.activeElement;
var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
evt.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, null, false, false, true, false, 0x79, 0);
focused.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this same question had been [asked previously on MozillaZine here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=835945).  That solution puts the context menu in the top left corner of the screen.  I tried using [the solution given to this other question about getting DOM screen positions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15706968/1015155) to produce the code below which places the context menu closer to the active element, but it is still buggy (sometimes the menu is a bit off from the element):

```
var target = (document.commandDispatcher.focusedElement || document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow.document.documentElement);

var screenX=0;
var screenY=0;
if ("boxObject" in target) {
  screenX=target.boxObject.x;
  screenY=target.boxObject.y;
} else {
  var box;
  try {
    box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  } catch(e) {}

  // Make sure we're not dealing with a disconnected DOM node
  if (box) {

    var body = document.body,
      clientTop = document.documentElement.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0,
      clientLeft = document.documentElement.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0,
      scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || body.scrollTop,
      scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || body.scrollLeft,
      top = box.top + scrollTop - clientTop,
      left = box.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft;
  }

  screenX=target.offsetLeft;
  screenY=target.offsetTop;
}

var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
e.initMouseEvent("contextmenu", true, false, null, 0, screenX, screenY, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
target.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not a expert but did you tried to find the setting's in about:config ?

if not then enter about:config in location box and hit enter and you will find lots of setting's there and do tell me if you find any setting's there or not .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did not find any relevant preference in `about:config`, but I checked on a different computer from the one I was originally using when I asked the question and discovered that I had actually made such a shortcut in Keyconfig on that computer (and I only realized this by looking in `about:config`).  From that old shortcut, I produced my answer.